# C++ trivial function: return value type doesn't match the function return type: ternary operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I cannot understand why would Visual Studio Intellisense complain.
In the code:

```
int absolute_value(int x) {
    return  x > 0 ?  x : - x;
}
```

It underlines `x` in `return x` with the message: return value type doesn't match the function return type.

Comment: Either a bug in *intellisense/visual studio* or something in your code/environment is missing from your example. Compiles fine in g++.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No underlines, no messages, everything compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My environment is win10, vs2022. I tested the code you posted, the code works fine, I suggest you repair your Visual Studio or download it again.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int absolute_value(int x) {
    return  x > 0 ? x : -x;
}
int main()
{
    cout << absolute_value(-6);
}
```

[image]